# sudoの実行時に求められるパスワードが分からない

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, sudo

環境
・Macのターミナル
・Linux Ubuntu

Linux初心者です。
manコマンドの日本語化をしようと思い、下記コマンドを実行したのですが、passwordを求められてしまいます。そのパスワードが分からずインストールが出来ないのですが、その場合どのように対処すれば良いでしょうか？
コマンドは、

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-ja manpages-ja-dev
```

です。
参考にしたサイト
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tettou77-2/20090323/1237833841

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: ご自身のアカウントのパスワードを入力すれば良いのですよ。それと、パッケージをインストール前に APT のパッケージリストをアップデートしておいた方が良いので `sudo apt-get update` を実行する事をお勧めします。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます！無事にコマンドを実行することが出来ました。

Answer (score 2):

あなたのアカウントのパスワードを入力しましょう。実際になんというパスワードかは、あなたしか知りません。
`chage`や`/etc/shadow`では見れないみたいなのでやっぱり`passwd`で変更するしかありません。

Comment: 現代的なシステムではパスワード自体は保存されません。`/etc/shadow`などにも、パスワードでは無くある手順で生成されたハッシュ値のみが入っています。（仮にパスワードそのものが書き込まれていたとしても、それを動いているシステムで読むのには`sudo`が必要で、結局パスワードが必要ですね。）

Comment: 確かにハッシュ値が書いてありました。編集しときます。@mjy

Comment: @poplot726 えっ「パスワードも『chage -l UserName』で確認することが出来ました」というのは本当ですか？ 上記コメントに書いた通り、現在のまともなシステムではパスワードを保存しません。（これは自分でWebサービスなどを作る際も基本です。）パスワードが見えたとしたら、何かマズイことになっている筈です。私は`chage`コマンドというのを知らなかったのですが、こういう事もありうるのでしょうか。

Comment: @mjy poplot726さんではありませんが調べてみるとパスワードの有効期限などの情報しか見えないのかも…(間違えすぎですね)

Comment: すみません、「chage -l UserName」コマンドではパスワードが見えた(確認できた)のではなく、コマンドが実行できてLast password changeとか、Password expiresとかの情報が表示されました。後から見た人が誤解しないようにパスワードを確認できました。のコメントは削除致しました。